# The Struct unpacking i only working in python 2 and i need to understand how to do it in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run this code in python 3 it only works in python 2

```
struct.unpack('f', "".join(map(chr, bytes)))[0]

def get_float(data, index):
    bytes = data[4*index:(index+1)*4]
    return struct.unpack('f', "".join(map(chr, bytes)))[0]
```

I get this error

> Type Error: a byte like object is required, not 'str"

Comment: What about it doesn't work in Python 3?

Comment: I get an error saying Type Error: a byte like object is required, not 'str" I'll add the code

Comment: struct.unpack() takes bytes as a second argument.

Comment: Sorry im really new to stack exchange give me a second

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
struct.unpack('f', b"".join(map(chr, bytes)))[0]
```

a b"" is a byte-string. Since the unpack need bytes, you need to use the byte-string join method.

EDIT: you don't need to map your bytes to char. You can use:

```
struct.unpack('f', bytes)[0]
```

Note that bytes shadow the class bytes.

Comment: You may want to explain why the `b` is needed