# struct unpack (Type Error: a byte like object is required, not 'str"), Unpack a List?

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, python-2to3

Attempting to use script that was built in Python 2, and now use it in Python 3 without adding a version 2 onto system. For the script, the only error I get is related to a struct.unpack at this line....

```
def go_parse(rec_list):
    size = (len(rec_list) - 4) / 4
    first_arg = "%sI" % size
    return struct.unpack(first_arg, (rec_list.rstrip ('\xff\xff\xff\xff')))
```

at line 4 of this function, I get the error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I read several other posts regarding this, and that it needs to be explicitly labeled as bytes, but I cant seem to figure out where to explicitly label that in this context.  The other examples on SO i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866887/the-struct-unpacking-i-only-working-in-python-2-and-i-need-to-understand-how-to) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252140/using-strings-and-byte-like-objects-compatibly-in-code-to-run-in-both-python-2), did not provide much of an explanation to it. The [struct pages](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/struct.html) don't seem to cover the error possibilities of 2-3...Only that *struct.unpack(fmt, buffer)* has the two arguments of fmt and buffer. Based on those examples, i have tried identifying this as bytes explicitly as a second arg using `b`, as well as `bytes` before the arguments and on the tuple for the .strip. I attempted return this as a `bytearray`, but that seemed to produce the same errors.

As an alternative, I am able to get the byte data I wanted into a list as shown below, what would be a way to get the list into unpack, attempt b'i' just looks at i as bytes.

```
list1 = [b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff',
b'\x07\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff']

print(struct.unpack('<s', bytes(i)))
```

The bytes are of varying length, but all end in \xff\xff\xff\xff. The data I am looking at is text, just trying to bring it back to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question spending some time in the Documentation, and someone pointing me in the right direction.

Generating a list of binary data that needed to be brought back to text for display, I used the [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html#text-encodings), a standard library.  All my binary data was saved into a list named bin_list.

```
import codecs

bin_list = [b'Some Binary data', b'some more binary data']

for i in bin_list:    # used the loop to print each to new line, nice and neat
    print (codecs.decode(i, "utf-8", "ignore"))   # or any other conversion avilable on codecs.
```